# 'Click and chat' Whatapp

Tags: c#, whatsapp

I wrote a small c# application to send messages to my relatives via the "Click and Chat"functionality of WhatsApp.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

private void webBrowser(string URL)
{
    WebBrowser webBrowser2 = new WebBrowser();
    webBrowser2.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
    webBrowser2.Navigate(URL);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    string s = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://www.funda.nl//koop/berkhout/huis-41021218-bobeldijk-26/").Replace(@" href=/", "") + "\n");
    webBrowser("https://wa.me/1234567 + "?text=" + s);
}

Process bProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("WhatsApp").FirstOrDefault();
if(bProcess != null)
{                   
    IntPtr p = bProcess.MainWindowHandle;
    SetForegroundWindow(p);
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
}
```

The above
works half. It opens the WhatsApp application on my computer and puts the message in the box, but the message isn't send automaticall, so obviously the SendKeys command isn't working. If i try to use the SendKeys command to send text and the enter key to e.g. 'Notepad' it works fine.
So actually I'm looking for a way to automate the Whattapp "send" command, so the message will be send automatically.

As Windows 10 doesn't allow Send Keys I have changed the register

**Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\EnableLUA to 0

Instead of the above SendKeys I have tried

```
const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
const Int32 VK_RETURN = 0x0D;

        PostMessage(p, WM_KEYDOWN, new IntPtr(VK_RETURN), new IntPtr(0));
        PostMessage(p, WM_KEYUP, new IntPtr(VK_RETURN), new IntPtr(0));
```

Unfortunately neither doesn't work.
Has anyone an idea how to auto-send a "click-and-chat" message without having to click the 'SEND' button manually?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I do have a solution for those who are interested. I have moved the "SendKeys" part to a timer instance that is enabled after the message has been send to "https://wa.me/" with a delay of 5 seconds.
After "pressing" the send button the timer is than unabled. Once I need my app to send a message it's just a matter of enabling the timer.

Not a very clean solution, but it works